# Clear Page - jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a page in jquery mobile which I fill dynamically per Javascript with HTML.

If the user goes to another page, I want to clear the dynamically added html-content from the page.

With the `.remove()` method, the whole page will be removed from the web-application.

Comment: Depends on which selector your using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use function **`empty()`** on a **`data-role="content"`** DIV and do it during the **`pagehide`** event.

Working example:

```
$(document).on('pagehide', '#index', function(){ 
    $('[data-role="content"]').empty();
});
```

In this case **`#index`** is a page id.